# Compare and Contrast IValidatableObject vs IValidator for MVC model validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

My understanding :
AFAIK, both IValidatableObject and IValidator interfaces validates the Model and helps displaying validation errors. The validate() method of IValidatableObject() returns an IEnumerable so that we can do multiple validations and display the validation results using the yield return pattern. Whereas the Validate() method of IValidator has a void return type and basically it sets the IsValid property and the ErrorMessage property. I guess we can do multiple validations here as well however the ErrorMessages has to be concatenated into a single property.

Are there any other differences/use cases that I'm missing?

P.S. [This](http://brendan.enrick.com/post/Validating-Entity-objects) is an interesting idea I came across, however this is a custom interface and not something .Net offers. However, I am only concerned about what .Net offers by default.

Comment: do you have any update on this?